# Javascript functions with different parameter passing

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

Recently i came through a fine example of javascript function. Please find in below code.

```
function add(a,b){
  return (a+b);
} 
console.log("Summation is===>",add(1,2));    
console.log("Summation is===>",add((1),(2)));
```

Both prints output has a 3.
What is the difference between two function arguments? How second function  arguments is different from first?

Comment: A LISP programmer has created the examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between two function arguments?

There is none whatsoever. With only a very few exceptions*, putting the grouping operator (`()`) around an already-isolated expression has no effect at all. The `1` and `2` in `add(1,2)` are already isolated.

---

* Some *(all? heh, probably not)* of the very few exceptions:

1. If you want to put the single expression in a `return` on a separate line from the return, e.g.:

   ```
   return            // WRONG
       expression;
   ```

   you have to put `()` around it like this:

   ```
   return (
       expression
   );
   ```

   to prevent the horror that is automatic semicolon insertion from adding a `;` after `return` where the line break is, creating a very subtle bug (since an expression on its own after `return;` is not an error, though a lint tool would hopefully help you catch it).
2. If you're using a concise body on an arrow function to return the result of an object initializer:

   ```
   () => {foo: "bar"} // WRONG
   ```

   you have to wrap the object initializer in `()` to avoid the `{` of the initializer being taken as the beginning of a function body, like this:

   ```
   () => ({foo: "bar"})
   ```
3. If you want to start a function expression where a statement is expected, you have to put something in front of the `function` keyword, since otherwise it will start a function *declaration* rather than function *expression*. It can be any of several things that tell the parser to switch from expecting a statement to expecting an expression, but `()` is a common choice, particularly for an IIFE:

   ```
   (function() { /*...*/})();
   ```

---

Side note: The grouping operator you're using in `return (a+b);` has no effect, as it's an isolated expression and you're not dealing with #1 above.